# Determine elements of a PHP expression

Tags: php, string, expression

Expressions like these:

- `$var`
- `function()`
- `$object->getProperty($var);`
- `$object->property`
- `$object->property->function($var)`
- `class::function()`

etc.

I want to get a list of all elements and what types they are. So for example:

`$object->property->function($var)`

the elements are:

- $object - variable
- property - property
- function() - function
- $var - variable

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) and its examples.

Comment: Great answer, but isn't it quite likely that the OP just wants print_r() or var_dump() ? EDIT: Just read the Q again and can't decide...

Comment: Well, it ain't all *that* easy, but having `token_get_all` it's pretty simple to write a little wrapper around that that gives you the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the answer from **deceze** you can also have a look at [NikiC's PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)

It turns code into a syntax tree rather than a list of tokens.