# Determine class of an object

Tags: php, class, expression

It know it can be done with `get_class($variable)`.
The problem is that my `$object` is actually a string containing the variable name.

so:

```
$object = new MyClass();

$var = '$object';

$class = get_class($var); // obviously fails
```

I can't use `get_class($object)`, because I don't have direct access to that variable (I'm producing the `$var` string from [parsing a PHP expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632001/determine-elements-of-a-php-expression) using token_get_all())

I tried using `eval(sprintf('return get_class(%s);', $var))`, but it doesn't work because the variable appear undefined from eval's scope :(

Is there a way to do this?

I need to know the class in order to pass it to ReflectionMethod, so I can get information about a method (the next element in the PHP expression).

---

NVM: I'm pretty sure it is not possible. Sorry for asking:)

Comment: @Andreas Linden shouldn't he strip the leading $ from $var to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

`$var = new $object();`

Answer (score 1):

Try using variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Something like:

```
$var = 'object';
$class = get_class( $$var );
```

Comment: I don't think its possible, unless the variable is exposed in the current scope :(

Comment: Oh, yeah, it does need to be in current scope. I'm not sure how you expect to access it otherwise. Where is the variable at?

Comment: it can be anywhere, like any file etc. Actually I'm getting the name by parsing the source PHP file which I get from debug_backtrace()...

Comment: Hmm I think maybe a better description of the problem would be helpful. You should update your question with some more information, like how you're trying to pull variables from previously loaded files in your backtrace. It may not be possible to do what you want to do, but you need to provide more info first. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
$ref = ltrim($var, '$');
get_class($ref);
```